# Como recibir datos JSON desde otro sitio WEB

Tags: javascript, json

Tengo un servicio web que envia datos a otro sitio web por el método POST y debo modificarlo para que obtenga una series de datos en formato JSON enviados desde otro sitio web, se puede decir que actúa como emisor y es necesario que actué como emisor y receptor de manera autónoma

De momento el backend todo esta en formato JavaScript.

```
                        /*Datos a enviar*/
                        var Obj_JSON = JSON.stringify(datos);
                        
                        /*servicio Emisor o Solicitud HTTP Request*/
                        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
                            if(this.readyState == 4 ){
                                msj.innerHTML = '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">Mensaje Enviado y respuesta de SiNaMed'+
                                                '<br> Estado de Respuesta: '+this.status+
                                                '<br> Respuesta: '+this.responseText+
                                                console.log(get_infoResponse(this.responseText,IdTE))
                                                '.</div>';
                                msj.style.display = 'inline';       

                            }else{
                                msj.innerHTML = '<div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">Mensaje no Enviado <br>.</div>';
                                msj.style.display = 'inline';
                            }
                        };
                        /*Direccion de envio*/
                        xhttp.open("POST","IP o DNS",true);
                        xhttp.setRequestHeader("Authorization","Bearer Vgwow9E98VwYB52Ejl4zNkcatViFPj29NwFS6v6GCK2pelsOJ7KNZi1l821v");
                        xhttp.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                        xhttp.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");
                        xhttp.send(Obj_JSON);
```

Ahora debo crear una función, método o clase que sea un receptor y todo el servicio se comporte como un servicio web 3.0
Alguna Idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero, necesitas habilitar CORS desde la web de destino

Con `.htaccess`

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

Con esto, harás que tu dominio de destino acepte peticiones desde cualquier origen, o puedes hacerlo desde un único origen con

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "https://dominio.com"
```

CORS es una política de compartimiento de recursos entre distintos orígenes, esta bloqueará las peticiones no coincidentes a las que tiene en la "lista blanca"

Antes de hacer cualquier petición, los navegadores hacen una inicial de tipo `OPTIONS` para comprobar que el origen se encuentre en la "lista blanca" del destino, de no encontrarse la petición será bloqueada

```
Has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Ahora que se entiende esto, hablemos del JavaScript

Puedes usar simplemente un `fetch()`

```javascript
fetch("https://url.com/recurso").then(response => {
    response.json().then(respuesta => {
        console.log(respuesta);
    });
});
```

**Métodos**

- El método `.then()` se usa para deducir si la petición fue exitosa
- El método `.text()` se usa para convertir la respuesta que se obtuvo a texto
- Y el método `.json ()` se usa para obtener la respuesta de la solicitud en JSON, esto arrojará un error si la solicitud no ha recibido una respuesta JSON (con un encabezado especificado por el servidor: `Content-Type: application/json`)
- El método `.catch ()` se usa para determinar si la solicitud tiene un error

```javascript
fetch("url", {
    method:"GET",
    body: {
        "hello":"world"
    }
})
```

La propiedad `body` es la información a enviar, puede enviarse como un `formData`, un objeto e incluso un string (`info=abc&other=bcd`)

- El método `.ok` se usa para verificar si la solicitud fue exitosa

---

#### Observaciones

- Estás tratando de enviar un encabezado para que el servidor acepte tu dominio, esto es incorrecto, debido a que `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` es un encabezado proporcionado por servidor y no modificable desde el cliente, si pones esto en una petición, el navegador se reusará a enviar la petición